# ASP.net MVC - create query in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm novice at MVC . I have 3 models: Department, Unit, Employees.

```
public class Department
{
public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
public int ManagerId { get; set; }
}

public class Unit
{
public int UnitID { get; set; }
public string UnitName { get; set; }
public int ManagerId
}

public class Employees
{
public int EmployeeId  { get; set; }
public string EmployeeName  { get; set; }
}
```

I want edit objects Unit and Department in single view. I use Structure view model:

```
public class StructureModel
{   
    public IEnumerable<Departments> Departments { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Units> Units { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

I want have in a view tables Departments and Units with a column ManagerName instead ManagerId (ManagerName == EmployeeName where Unit.ManagerId == Employee.EmployeeId) . My controller:

```
private RegistraiContext db = new RegistraiContext();
    public ActionResult Index()        {
        var model = new StructureModel();
        model.Departments = db.Departmentss.ToList().OrderBy(r => r.DepartmId);
        model.Units = db.Unitss.ToList().OrderBy(r => r.UnitId);
        return View(model);
    }
```

And finally my view (I use Grid.Mvc)

```
@model Registrai.Models.StructureModel
@using GridMvc.Html
@Html.Grid(Model.Unit).Columns(columns =>
{
columns.Add(model => model.UnitId).Titled("UniId")
columns.Add(model => model.UnitName).Titled("UnitName");
columns.Add(model => model.ManagerName).Titled("Manager");
}
.........................
```

Where (in model Unit, in StructureModel or in controller) and how to create query to retrieve ManagerName from DB and how to modify models Unit and Department to add property ManagerName ? 
Thank you

Comment: you need view model which will be specific to view requirements

Comment: Can you help with code?